# hide redundant tuple if it is contained in another tuple in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a holidays table for a person, say 'M109'.
for a particular date he taken vacation for 1 hour lunch and 4 hour meeting.

eg.

- 11 am to 3 pm - meeting
- 12pm to 1pm - lunch.

now I need to hide this 1 hour lunch tuple and get only the meeting tuple.
how can i do that ?

`table(Person(varchar), StartTime, EndTime, Date, Desciption)` is the schema.

My query so far:

```
select "Provider", sum(b."EndTime" - b."StartTime")/60 as Non
from VACATION b
where b."StartDate" = '18-FEB-13'
and b."StartTime" IN (select p."StartTime"
                      from axium.VACATION p
                      where Exists (select q."StartTime"
                                    from axium.VACATION q
                                    where p."Provider" = q."Provider"
                                    and q."StartTime" <> p."StartTime"
                                    and q."StartTime" between p."StartTime"
                                                      and p."EndTime"
                                   )
                     )
and b."Provider" = 'M1009'
group by b."Provider"
order by b."Provider";
```

Comment: how would you do so? What is your criteria?

Comment: how do you store that values for lunch and meeting?

Comment: Please show us sample data

Comment: i have given a table in which a workers lunch and meeting time are given. Now i have been asked to get the total non working hours(eg. Lunch, Meeting) fro a day and that should come out to be 4 hours.
but my query gives 5 hours also counting the lunch hour, but logically that i hour lunch should be included in 4 hours meeting non working time

Comment: What datatype is `StartTime`?

Comment: Also, I think your first inner query needs to be correlated - i.e. there's a missing `and p."Provider" = b."Provider"`

Comment: starttime is in minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `where` clause and correlated subquery:

```
select *
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.person = t.person and t2.starttime < t.starttime and t2.endtime > t.endtime)
```

Comment: select "Provider", sum(b."EndTime" - b."StartTime")/60 as Non from VACATION b
 where b."StartDate" = '18-FEB-13' and b."StartTime"  IN
 (select p."StartTime" from axium.VACATION p where  Exists (select q."StartTime" from axium.VACATION q where p."Provider" = q."Provider" 
  and q."StartTime" <> p."StartTime" 
  and  q."StartTime"  between p."StartTime" and p."EndTime" )
 )
 and b."Provider" = 'M1009'
 group by b."Provider"
 order by b."Provider";

Comment: no it is not working I tried that before.
The data is confidential and i cant report it here.
i have three tuples of non working hours of a person.

11 am -3pm - meeting(desciprtion)
12pm - 1 pm - lunch
4pm - 5 pm - left early

result should be 5 hours, but my query is counting as 6 hours.

Comment: and i just sent you my query

Comment: @ShirajSood, I think you need to use `NOT EXISTS`, not `EXISTS`.